# .htaccess remove .html extension and add trailing slash and disallow .html files

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a static website with html files and I want to call them without the .html ending and a trailing slash.

For example:

```
www.test.com/test.html
```

Should be available under

```
www.test.com/test/
```

I managed this with the following .htaccess

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.html
```

But both versions of the url lead to the same page. How can I redirect (without .html) or throw a 404 for the .html version?

```
www.test.com/test.html
```

This is the working solution with a trailing slash. Thank you @arkascha!

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)\.html$ /$1/ [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.html [END]
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, add another rule that explicitly redirects requests to URLs with "file name extensions"...

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)\.html$ /$1/ [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
RewriteRule ^/?([^\.]+)/?$ /$1.html [END]
```

If the above rule set results in a http status 500 ("server internal error"), then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. In that case you have to use the `L` flag instead of the `END` flag and add an additional condition to the first block:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)\.html$ /$1/ [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^/?([^\.]+)/?$ /$1.html [L]
```

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only supported as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: I tried this already. This is not working because it ends in an infinity loop. (5th line the trailing slash is missing: RewriteRule ^/?(.+)\.html$ /$1/ [R=301])

Comment: I don't see how the above rule set should end in an endless rewriting loop... Sure you did not try something _similar_? About that trailing slash: it is uncommon to add such a slash which is why I left it out...

Comment: I copied your code 1:1 and google chrome ends with an ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS . I tried it with different browsers and computers. Try it on your own, you will have the same issue.

Comment: I do have to apologize! You certainly are right... I more or less blindly copied your code without thinking ;-) I added an `[END]` flag to the last rule to prevent the rewriting engine to enter another loop which would indeed cause the issue you observed.

Comment: I also added a workaround version for older apache http server versions (prior to version 2.4).

Comment: Thank you! Now it works perfectly. I will edit my post and add my trailing slash version. I have no access to the virtual host configuration...

Comment: I added that trailing slash, since you insist ;-) Though I still do not understand why you want that...

Comment: Because all my pages have a trailing slash. So I want to keep my pattern. Is there anything against a trailing slash?

Comment: No technical reason against it. Only it is not required and somewhat confusing. At least you should allow and serve requests without that trailing slash. The slash indicates that you are still thinking in terms of "folders" and "files" instead of in _objects_ as it makes more sense with http.